# Clustering data points based on row "distance"

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a dataset with a number of timestamps. I want to cluster them in groups where each group consists of data points that are not further than X hours apart. That means that each group with be a latest X hours apart.

Any ideas on how to do that?

Comment: you cannot do this. clustering can be done on specific columns (up to four) only. submit [feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187149&template=0) is the only what you can do so far

Comment: Clustering does not support this, it is "automatic" clustering so it will be based on the amount of data and cardinality with using user specified ranges.
To clarify, it sounds like you want something like range partitioning? Specify ranges of values that the data will be partitioned by, ie. range between a to b, in intervals of x?

Answer (score 1):

You'd have to introduce a column by which you can cluster. If I understand you correctly it is about hours in time. Since you need to decide whether a row is in a cluster or not, you can not have a dynamic distance cluster.
But you can extract the hour information and use that to create your cluster. 
E.g. using `hour - modulo of (hour / group size)`

```sql
WITH a AS (
  SELECT * FROM UNNEST([
    TIME(0,40,0), TIME(1,23,0),
    TIME(2,12,0), TIME(3,51,0),
    TIME(4,1,0),  TIME(5,51,0),
    TIME(6,5,0),  TIME(7,21,0),
    TIME(8,56,0), TIME(9,34,0),
    TIME(10,23,0),TIME(20,04,0),
    TIME(23,43,0)
  ]) as time
)

SELECT 
  time,
  EXTRACT(HOUR FROM time) one,
  EXTRACT(HOUR FROM time)-MOD(EXTRACT(HOUR FROM time),2) two,
  EXTRACT(HOUR FROM time)-MOD(EXTRACT(HOUR FROM time),3) three,
  EXTRACT(HOUR FROM time)-MOD(EXTRACT(HOUR FROM time),4) four
FROM a
```

So it's groups of hours of a certain size.